# How to promote a build when certain value in output is above threshold?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the [Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) and I'd like to promote my freestyle job to have a gold star when a certain value in my output is above a given threshold (e.g. above 1.00).

Here is a sample output from backtesting jobs:

```
Pass  Profit Total trades Profit factor Expected Payoff Drawdown $ Drawdown %
   1  622.71           76          1.38            8.19     526.77       4.94
  10  301.09           36          1.38            8.36     526.77       4.93
  14  240.96           62          1.18            3.89     589.60       5.60
```

My aim is to promote the build to gold when the first line right after the header line has a `Profit factor` column value above `1.00` and only to silver star when it is below.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is at the [bottom](https://github.com/jenkinsci/promoted-builds-plugin#job-dsl-support) of the GitHub [README](https://github.com/jenkinsci/promoted-builds-plugin) describing [Job DSL](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl) for the [Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin). Link to GitHub is on every plugin's page. There are also links to plugins it depends on and you should read the documentation for those like the [Job DSL plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki) wiki. You can also ask questions in the Job DSL [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/job-dsl-plugin) or simply read the [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-DSL-Commands). Here is a [plugin](https://github.com/codecentric/job-dsl-promotions-plugin) that extends the promotion syntax of the DSL.